# c2dm not supported ,any alternative?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

According to the message included in [c2dm website](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/) it seems that cloud to device is not supported anymore. I know that it's clearly specified there but, just to clarify it one more time (cause I really need a new user), is there any possible way to obtain any new senderId/quota to operate with c2dm?

Comment: GCM is slightly retooled C2DM. Read the migration guide.

Comment: I am aware of that, but I need c2dm registration right away for a release. It's simply not straight forward including the server updates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot get senderids or change your quota any more. C2DM has been completely replaced as of today by [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html).

Comment: I also read it and that's my main concern. It has been blocked for good, no alternative for registering anything for c2dm (and not GCM) I guess

Comment: You should check out the [Migration guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/c2dm.html). If you already have your server happily working with C2DM, I **believe** it will continue to work with new clients (registration IDs) for some undetermined length of time.